# Scheduling rake tasks with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, whenever, rufus-scheduler

I'm trying to use either whenever/rufus-scheduler gems to schedule rake tasks to run in Sinatra.  I can't seem it get the tasks to run.

Here is what I've been trying:

```
class App < Sinatra::Base
...
    configure :development do
       every 1.minute do
         p "The task is running"
       end     
    end
end
```

Any ideas why this isn't working? Is this the best place to call this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the offical Github page of rufus-scheduler here: https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'rufus/scheduler'

class App < Sinatra::Base
  scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new

  scheduler.every '5s' do
      puts "task is running"
  end

end

a = App.new
```

This puts the string on the console in every 5 seconds. You can replace that with your own code.

Comment: If you're using rufus-scheduler 3.x, then you initialize it with `Rufus::Scheduler.new`, just for reference.